# Change runner architecture on hosted GitLab

Tags: node.js, gitlab, cicd, armv8

Good Day Friends!

I have nodejs code that is running on an ARMv8 SoC on DietPi OS (Debian). I can package and execute the code with [`pkg`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pkg?activeTab=readme).
Now I want that code to be packaged and uploaded to a website in a CI/CD job.

Depending on the architecture of the OS different `.so` are installed. By default the docker image architecture is selected depending on the host that is pulling. GitLab CI/CD jobs seem to be amd64 by default.

Is it possible to change GitLab runner architecture?

Is it possible to force to pull an aarch64 image from DockerHub for my job?

Is there a workaround, where I pull aarch64 `.so` independent from my current architecture?

Thanks in advance!